# Azure DevOps - There are no changes to merge between the selected branches

Tags: git, azure-devops

Our team is working with **Azure DevOps** where we have a **Git** repository. We have different branches there called **master**, **dev** and the additional feature branches originated from **dev**.

The problem what I face is when I would like to do a pull request from one of the feature branches to **dev** the following warning message appears on **Azure DevOps**:

> There are no changes to merge between the selected branches.

I saved, added, committed and pushed my changes into the feature branch. Also if I run `git diff dev` then it reports properly the changes.

The weird thing is there are definitely changes in the feature branch - left one is **dev** branch and the right one is the feature branch - just like below:

[image: diff-between-branches]

It's happening since there was a revert from `master` to `dev` branch earlier.

By any chance if anyone has an idea what to check or what to do to be able to merge and see the changes between these branches when creating pull request, please don't hesitate to share, would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you also try with using the **Compare** feature in Azure Devops? https://imgur.com/a/6K5BoKp Ensure the changes also exists in Azure Devops repository.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Thank you for the idea but the **Compare** unfortunately shows: `No changes between these branches.`

Comment: Okay. This means in Azure Devops repository, there's no changes between these 2 branches. Can you sure that the changes indeed be pushed into the Azure Devops?  You can check the last commit of the corresponding branch in Azure Devops to confirm that. (Please check this in Azure Devops instead of locally)

Answer (score 1):

Not to worry, I faced this exact issue yesterday. My manager and myself was trying to find a fix for this issue. All we had to do was to revert the revert commit. Please find how to do so in the below link.
https://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt